How to calculate my overtime (pm to am) in Google sheets?
My table
I have a problem when I try to calculate my Overtime and I'm looking for a working formula that can help me.
The formula, I use works for me perfect when I don't work from evening to early morning.
I attached a screenshot.
A mean the day.
B mean "Start"
C mean "Stop"
D mean "Weekend"
E mean "Working hours"
F mean "Regular hours"
G mean "Overtime"
I tried one arrayformula but it didn't worked for me.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.





A
B
C




1
23:00
7:00
=B1-A1


2
12:30
22:00
=B2-A2



This seems to be produce the correct answers like:




A
B
C




1
23:00
7:00
8:00


2
12:30
22:00
9:30



P.S. The first one, showing the formulas, is done using CTRL+` in Google Sheets.
When selecting column C, and choosing Format/Number/Duration, this is shown:




A
B
C




1
23:00
7:00
-16:00:00


2
12:30
22:00
9:30:00




Thank you! This works but when I try to calculate my Overtime it doesn't give me the right results. It gives me results with minuses.

I added some info about Formatting/Number/Duration, but it's still not clear what you are doing to see minutes .
